# Wix velo | Why aren't my http functions working?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, velo

I have an online store, hosted by Wix. I use the Wix Editor, with "dev mode" enabled, and I have installed the velo package `wix-store-data-requests`, which exposes some http endpoints for working with my store's product data.

But when I query those functions with an http request, all I get is a 500 status code and response text  `` `x-wix-function-user-error` header missing exception ``. I can't find any reference to this exception in the documentation.

The following code was copied into my site's (otherwise empty) `http-functions.js` file, as directed in the `wix-stores-data-requests` package readme.

```
import {
    get_storeInfo as _get_storeInfo,
    put_updateProduct as _put_updateProduct,
    get_products as _get_products
} 
from '@velo/wix-stores-data-requests-backend';

export async function get_storeInfo(request) {
    return await _get_storeInfo(request);
}

export async function put_updateProduct(request) {
    return await _put_updateProduct(request);
}

export async function get_products(request) {
    return await _get_products(request);
}
```

I'm calling those functions with the following python code.

```
import requests
from _tokens_ import get_token

token = get_token("wix")      #my "store secret", as directed by the readme

# url for get_storeInfo 
#   response body should include some json with the store name and other details
url = "https://my.site/store/_functions/storeInfo"

r=requests.get(url , headers = {'secretauth' : token})
print(r.status_code) #prints '500'
print(r.text)        #prints  '`x-wix-function-user-error` header missing exception'
```

The request does not seem to be reaching the actual function at all. The response is the same, even if I deliberately misspell the function url: a get request to `https://my.site/store/_functions/someGibberish` would receive the same response.

The most frustrating aspect is that I *did* get it work, once, a few weeks ago. This was in an interactive python session, so I can't reconstruct exactly what I did.

I'm stumped. Thanks in advance for your time looking over this.

Comment: Did you set `storeUrl` property in the backend config.json file ?